# Is there a way to link yet to be created images into an indesign layout?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm creating a multipage publication with many ads that haven't been built yet. I know their size, and filename, but the image/pdf doesn't exist yet.

Is there an existing script or a possible way to link an image that doesn't exist? Another way to look at this would be kind of the reverse of how the missing links (relink) button works. Where I know what the file path will be, but the file is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing industry standard practice:

Rather than a script, just create a blank image at the exact size. Make it florescent magenta with the letters "FPO" huge and dead-centre so no one can mistake it for the real thing.

Importantly: give this FPO image the *exact* file name of the file which will eventually be used/placed.

When your production image is finalized and approved, cut-and-paste the exact FPO file name into the new file. Drop the production file into your working directory **overwriting** the FPO file, and refresh it in InDesign. Bob's your uncle.

If this is being done to hundreds of images, you can develop your own batch process to handle this with some time-saving automation. However, *this is a good example of an issue that can be solved at the production-management level, rather than at the coding level.*

Hoping this helps!

Comment: Also, If you know in advance the dimensions of the ads/images that haven't been built yet then consider using an _"FPO image"_ image (i.e. a placeholder image) that has the same dimensions as the final intended image. By doing this you'll negate the need to re-position/scale/crop each image when refreshing the links (i.e. updating the links) in inDesign.